# Connection String Problem

Tags: c#

I am a programmer trying to teach myself C#. I am trying to connect the the `Northwind.mdf` database in a form. I have used the Database Explorer to attach the database to the form, and the test connection button worked. For the connection string I am using `"server=.\\sqlexpress; Trusted_Connection=yes; database=Northwind"` This connection fails in `SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);` Google has been no help. Any ideas?

Comment: Whenever you have some sort of error you want to ask other people about, please say what the error is instead of just what it is that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

`Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;`

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the connection in the "Database Explorer".
Click on "Properties".
See the "Connection String" in the properties window, with its value on the right.
***Is this the same connection string, as the one you posted?***

Here is the connection string, I could see with a new mdf file I created

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\kalpesh\Documents\test.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```

Assuming that the connection string is correct, you will have to escape it in c# (if it contains any of the characters that requires it. for e.g. the backslash character)

```
string connectionstring = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\kalpesh\Documents\test.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
```

In your case, it should be the path to the `Northwind.mdf` located on your machine.
Does this work?